# itextsharp search pdf and extract found pages to another pdf

Tags: vb.net, itext

Can anyone show me how to extract pages based on page numbers found in search and create new pdf to be able to print? What I have in mind is I will search a pdf using vb.net and the pages that have my answer will be extracted to another pdf and in the end of search it will print the new pdf. What I have done till now is I have done the search and it returns page number for the correct results, but I dont know from here what to do please see below:

```
Public Shared Function SearchTextFromPdf(ByVal sourcePdf As String, ByVal searchPhrase As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim fBrowse As New OpenFileDialog
    With fBrowse

        .Filter = "PDF Files(*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files(*.*)|*.*"
        .Title = "Choose Pdf"
    End With
    If fBrowse.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        sourcePdf = fBrowse.FileName
    Else
        Exit Function

    End If

    Dim foundList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim raf As iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray = Nothing
    Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing
    Try
        raf = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourcePdf)
        reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(raf, Nothing)
        If caseSensitive = False Then
            searchPhrase = searchPhrase.ToLower()
        End If
        For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages()
            Dim pageText As String = iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i)
            If caseSensitive = False Then
                pageText = pageText.ToLower()
            End If
            If pageText.Contains(searchPhrase) Then
                MsgBox(i)
                foundList.Add(i)

            End If
        Next
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return foundList
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim sourceFile As String = "D:\source.pdf"
    Dim resultFile As String = "D:\result.pdf"
    Dim arrayOfPages As Integer() = {1, 5, 7, 9}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ExtractPages(sourceFile, arrayOfPages)
End Sub

Public Sub ExtractPages(sourcePdfFile As String, pagesForExtracting As Integer())

    Dim reader As New PdfReader(sourcePdfFile)
    Dim document As New Document(reader.GetPageSize(1))
    Dim pdfCopy As New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(resultFile, FileMode.Create))

    Try
        document.Open()

        For Each pageNumber As Integer In pagesForExtracting
            Dim importedPage As PdfImportedPage = pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber)
            pdfCopy.AddPage(importedPage)
        Next

        Dim text As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy())
        document.Close()
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

If pdfCopy throws null reference exception - you have to ignore this exception, choosing Continue in Visual Studio IDE

Comment: Thank you so much i will try it and update you, but why would it give an exception?

Comment: This exception is from itextSharp.dll - VS IDE give message : Loaded 'itextsharp.dll' module was built without symbols.